# calculating HRMS using NMEA sentences including GPGGA , GPGSV, GLGSV, QZGSV,QZGSA, GPGSA?

Tags: gps, android, satellite, mathematics, nmea

I have NMEA sentences including  GPGGA , GPGSV, GLGSV, QZGSV,QZGSA, GPGSA and GNGSA. my goal is to achieve HRMS accuracy meter. produced android devices for special intent gives GP/GN GST nmea message which includes latitude and longitude error meters but android device that I have is not produced for special aim and dosent give GP/GN GST nmea message.  I dont know How I am able to calcute HRMS value as meter. On the other hand, when Location is changed Android locationlibrary provide accuracy as meters. But I would like to calculate Horizontal accuracy using nmea messages. is there any way to calculate HRMS value using messages that I mentioned above of this writing.

```
nmea messages
$GPGSA
GPS DOP and active satellites

eg1. $GPGSA,A,3,,,,,,16,18,,22,24,,,3.6,2.1,2.2*3C
eg2. $GPGSA,A,3,19,28,14,18,27,22,31,39,,,,,1.7,1.0,1.3*35


1    = Mode:
       M=Manual, forced to operate in 2D or 3D
       A=Automatic, 3D/2D
2    = Mode:
       1=Fix not available
       2=2D
       3=3D
3-14 = IDs of SVs used in position fix (null for unused fields)
15   = PDOP
16   = HDOP
17   = VDOP
```

http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/